# combine tibbles with inexact values

Tags: r

I have two tibbles and I want to combine them based on the Batsman column. However, the values in the 2 columns are not completely identical, i.e. "V Kohli" vs. "Virat Kohli (IND)". How can I combine the tibbles based on these inexact matches?

Thank you!

```
x1 <- tibble(Batsman=c("V Kohli (INDIA)","RG Sharma (INDIA)","Babar Azam (PAK)","GJ Maxwell (AUS)"),
                       Runs=c(500,400,300,200),
                       Matches=c(67,54,47,23)  

x2 <- tibble(Rank=c(1,2,3,4),
             Batsman=c("Virat Kohli", "Rohit Sharma", "Glenn Maxwell","Babar Azam"),
             Rating=c(853,820,640,500))
```

Comment: Didn't you ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164667/combining-tables-based-on-different-row-values) again?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to join two texts strings,

```
> x1$Batsman
[1] "V Kohli (INDIA)"   "RG Sharma (INDIA)" "Babar Azam (PAK)"  "GJ Maxwell (AUS)" 
> x2$Batsman
[1] "Virat Kohli"   "Rohit Sharma"  "Glenn Maxwell" "Babar Azam"
```

I guess you have much more names than these four?
It is definitely a tricky task, computer are notoriously bad at doing these kind of tasks. (There is some famous examples of very long function just to read phone numbers). From the strings you provide, i can see they always have similar names.

I would use [stringr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0) to extract the names with a regexp.

The full code:

```
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

x1 <- tibble(Batsman=c("V Kohli (INDIA)","RG Sharma (INDIA)","Babar Azam (PAK)","GJ Maxwell (AUS)"),
             Runs=c(500,400,300,200),
             Matches=c(67,54,47,23) )

x2 <- tibble(Rank=c(1,2,3,4),
            Batsman=c("Virat Kohli", "Rohit Sharma", "Glenn Maxwell","Babar Azam"),
            Rating=c(853,820,640,500))


AA <- str_sub(x1$Batsman, start = str_locate(x1$Batsman, " ")[,1]+1, 20)
AA <- str_sub(AA, start = 1, end = str_locate(AA, " ")[,1]-1)  %>%
  str_to_lower()


BB <- str_sub(x2$Batsman, start = str_locate(x2$Batsman, " ")[,1]+1, 20) %>%
  str_to_lower()

match(AA, BB)
```